# Parameter 0 of constructor in 'com.example..'. required a bean of type 'com.example...' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring

I'm building my first Spring project, I have very little experience in Java and I'm overwhelmed by the amount of boiler plate. This issue seems to be really simple and I found a lot of related answers. However, none of them seems to address this issue specifically.
I haven't done any special configurations, I only built this with Spring Boot and created 3 classes.
When I run the project I get the following message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.Student.StudentController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.Student.StudentService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.Student.StudentService' in your configuration.
```

I renamed the class "StudentService", and maybe this is the source of the issue.

This is my project structure:

```
- JAVA PROJECTS
  - src/main/java
    - com.example.demo
      - DemoApplication
    - com.example.demo.Student.StudentService
      - Student
      - StudentController
      - StudentService
  - src/main/resources
  - src/test/java
  - JRE System Library [JAVA SE-17]
  - Maven Dependencies
```

And this is `StudentService.java`:

```
package com.example.demo.Student;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

public class StudentService {
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return List.of(
            new Student(
                1L, 
                "George", 
                "george.email@gmail.com", 
                LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 5), 
                22)
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Well .... You don't have a _bean_ of type `StudentService` in your application context. Either annotate it with `@Component` or `@Service`, or define such a `@Bean` in a _configuration_ class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Several ways to resolve this !***

1. `Annotate` your StudentService class with `@Component`, during start up of application, Spring will identify this and create a bean in IOC container for use. ( Don't forget to use `@ComponentScan(basePackages={com.example.demo.Stude...})` on top of your `DemoApplication` class )
2. Create a Configuration class with `@Configuration` and define your own bean with `@Bean` returning instance of StudentService

Eventually, use `@Autowired` on top of your StudentService instance in Controller. Like below

```
<pre>public class Controller
{
@Autowired
StudentService service; 
// so on 
} </pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no bean defined for the StudentService class.
try defining the class with the following  :

1. @Service - If the StudentService class need to defined as a service class
2. @Component

either of the way will work for you.

Comment: Indeed both worked, what's the difference between @Service and @Component?